# He who gives Information?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the person who gives you information called?
Basically I have read a play in which there are two characters that provide you information of the happenings in the play like the information that is important for the play . Now they are not narrators as such but they are normal characters of the play that converse and the readers are acquainted with some significant information?  So what can they be called ?  Like in this sentence : Salarino and Salanio play the role of ___________ (those who convey information ) in Act 2 scene 8.

P.S. : To be more specific this is with reference to Salarino and Salanio in the merchant of venice by Shakepeare  . And i am not happy with the word information tellers  since I want a single sophisticated word.

Comment: Perhaps "informants" would work?

Comment: What is your definition of "sophisticated word"? How will you use the word? Can you show us an example sentence where this word would be used? Why would "informer" or "information provider" not work?

Comment: A sophisticated word refers to the best fitting word ..

Comment: @Rathony .... informers has a different connotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "person who gives you information" is called an *expository character*.

> **Expository** *adjective*
>   Intended to explain or describe something
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expository)

Here's an example of the phrase in use (bold added; italics in original):

> Finally, according to Rowling, next to Albus Dumbledore, Hermione is the perfect **expository character**; because of her encyclopaedic knowledge, she can always be used as a plot dump to explain the *Harry Potter* universe.
>   [- Harry Potter: The Complete Guide, Editor: By Wikipedians](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=n3vng7gyGCYC&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=%22expository%20character%22&source=bl&ots=8_07PhQV8j&sig=EhWoppy3bGVgdMSvfjASTMNv2So&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtm8CExfvMAhUj5aYKHXROBMsQ6AEIPjAI#v=onepage&q=%22expository%20character%22&f=false)

TV Tropes also uses the term informally:

> **Mr Exposition**
>   A character whose purpose is to provide Infodumps and explain the plot. Ostensibly, this is for the benefit of the protagonists, but most of the time their real reason for existing is to provide Exposition to the audience.
>   [- tvtropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MrExposition)

Answer (score 1):

in·form·ant

inˈfôrmənt/

noun

a person who gives information to another.

another term for informer.

In this case it would be plural

**informants**

I could be this single word choice. As informants take part in the "acting" of an investigation.

Comment: Is that suitable for characters in a play?

Comment: It would be suitable by definition.

Comment: Yeah but not by common usage

Comment: The word informers might better represent the two characters.

Answer (score 0):

*Docent* according to dictionary.com is

> a person who is a knowledgeable guide, especially one who conducts visitors through a museum and **delivers a commentary** on the exhibitions